# Jsoup remove specific TR id

Tags: java, html-table, jsoup

I try to remove a "TR" on a table with specific id, where I'm got from

```
String url = "http://citraslider.blogspot.com/2014/03/table-model.html";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
System.out.println(doc);
```

And print:

```
<table id="mt" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="hbtbl">
    <tr id="1"><td class="aa"><div class="bb">11</div><a href="mailto:asd@yahoo.com" target="_blank"><b class="nme pn_std">bua</b></a>: ask 1 ?</td></tr>
    <tr id="2"><td class="a"><div class="b">12</div><a href="mailto:asd@yahoo.com" target="_blank"><b class="nme pn_std">bua</b></a>: ask 2 ?</td></tr>
    <tr id="3"><td class="aa"><div class="bb">13</div><a href="mailto:asd@yahoo.com" target="_blank"><b class="nme pn_std">bua</b></a>: ask 3 ?</td></tr>
    <tr id="-1"><td class="a"><div align="center"><a href="javascript:void(window.open('index.php?mid=1&btag=awe&i='+((cf.op)?cf.op:8304), 'archive', 'width=320,height=400,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'));">[prev]</a></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is:

```
Elements elemen= doc.select("tr");
Elements el = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("id", "-1");
el.remove(0);
System.out.println(el); // Here its work
for (Element e : elemen) {
    System.out.println(e.text()+":"+e.attr("id")); // But at this line still show [prev], tr id="-1" still show
    e.getElementsByAttributeValue("id", "-1").remove();
}
```

So, how i can remove "tr id=-1" on a loop results?

```
    <tr id="-1"><td class="a"><div align="center"><a href="javascript:void(window.open('index.php?mid=1&btag=awe&i='+((cf.op)?cf.op:8304), 'archive', 'width=320,height=400,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'));">[prev]</a></div></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your selector to exclude `tr` for `id = -1`

```
Elements elemen= doc.select("tr").not("tr#-1");
```

More information on the [selector syntax here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Code becomes,

```
Elements elemen= doc.select("tr").not("tr#-1");
        for (Element e : elemen) {
            System.out.println(e.text()+":"+e.attr("id"));

        }
```

Gives,

```
11bua: ask 1 ?:1
12bua: ask 2 ?:2
13bua: ask 3 ?:3
```

Comment: what id the id has a name as download. For ex :- <tr id="download">,how to exclude this ?